# Payment issues with Play Store and multiple accounts

Tags: android

I've been having issues adding a debit card to my main google account, so instead I logged in with a separate account and added the debit card to that second account.

Then, when I would try to do any sort of in-app purchase, it would only allow/show info for my main account. Even after uninstalling the app, switching to my secondary account, and reinstalling the app, going to the in-app purchase would just show payment methods for my main account, with no option to switch to my secondary account.

Okay, fine, so I take a drastic measure and just remove my main account all together. Now of course all my contacts are messed up, but no big deal. Finally, I can install the app and make the purchase. Payment successful.

So then I go back to add my main account back to my phone, and go into the app and it has a big friendly "You must upgrade!"

???????????????

I just upgraded! It said payment successful, I never uninstalled the app after purchasing it, etc. This is getting really frustrating, and looking at other solutions, none have worked for me so far. Someone elsewhere mentioned downloading the app from the web's play store, but I can't figure out how to go to the play store's website on my phone without having it just open the app.

Comment: Is your application released on a alpha channel?

Comment: no, it's been on the play store for nearly a year now